# How to uninstall all ruby gems on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems

How to uninstall all ruby gems on Windows? Is it possible with single command?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One line to rule them all. Power shell not needed. From command prompt run:

```
ruby -e "`gem list`.split(/$/).each { |line| puts `gem uninstall -Iax #{line.split(' ')[0]}` unless line.empty? }"
```

Just copy / paste and voila!

Answer (score 15):

I've found an elegant solution `gem list | %{$_.split(' ')[0]} | %{gem uninstall -Iax $_ }` and `Windows Powershell`

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the contents of your gems folder. Where this is will depend on how you installed Ruby and RubyGems, as well as the Ruby version. For instance, if you used the one-click installer for 1.9.2p180, and installed rubygems with ruby setup.rb, the gems folder would be c:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\ - delete everything under that folder and poof! your gems are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gem env` on your console will provide something like this:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
    - C:/Users/Luis/Tools/ruby/ruby-1.8.7-p334-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

If you browse using Explorer into that directory will find a series of folders that represent all the installed gems (`cache`, `doc`, `spec`, `gems`)

Remove all of them and it will remove all your gems.

Now, this will not remove any executable script installed by one of these gems. If you installed `rake` or `rails` gems, these scripts (as `rails` and `rails.bat` will remain in your Ruby `bin` directory.

You will also need to remove them manually.