# RailsInstaller: Can I maintain the gem fold when re-installing a new version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

This is on Windows.

I just upgrade from `Ruby 1.9.3` to `Ruby 2.1.0` using RailsInstaller( and with other component like git, devkit, etc..). I doing this by uninstall the previous version, and then install a newer one.

The problem is that after uninstall , there is a `Ruby1.9.3` left, with gem previouslly installed.

Now, since I upgrade to `Ruby2.1.0`, can I re-use this fold's gems? If so, How?
Or I just delete that folder and re-install every gem again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gems are specific to ruby version.

You should just delete the `ruby1.9.3` related folder, and re-install all the gems for ruby `2.1.0` version by running `bundle install`.

No harm in leaving behind the ruby 1.9.3 gems as well, but a good practice to remove them.

[How to uninstall all ruby gems on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373160/how-to-uninstall-all-ruby-gems-on-windows)